# How do I get to use XAML2009 features

Tags: xaml, .net-4.0

I've been reading a little about teh new features available through XAML2009. How do I get to use them in VS2010 (.net 4.0)?

Specifically, I want to use `x:Arguments` and want to know which namespace I need to include (if any).

I've read this from the documentation (below), but I can't figure how to get round it? Should I just not use thie new features?

> In WPF, you can use XAML 2009
>   features, but only for XAML that is
>   not WPF markup-compiled.
>   Markup-compiled XAML and the BAML form
>   of XAML do not currently support the
>   XAML 2009 language keywords and
>   features.

Comment: Question is clear, and you are using SO => not stupid.

Comment: thanks Richard, but I really wish someone would give a go at answering my question :-(

Comment: Anybody know what the curren't status of XAML2009 is at this point? I mean is it still even on the table for being added to wpf (in compiled code)? Or is this going to be skipped and incorporated into metro in some fashion?

Answer (score 1):

MS was unable to bring XAML2009 to VS2010 (designer + XAML editor) before it was released. We have to wait till the next version or maybe service pack.

http://blogs.windowsclient.net/rob_relyea/archive/2009/05/20/yes-xaml2009-isn-t-everywhere-yet.aspx